# How to perform FSK modulation in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, digital-modulation, fsk

FSK Modulation in VHDL

Hello,
 I have a VHDL block that performs FSK modulation. It looks like this

[image]

The operation of the VHDL block goes like this. Fsk_data selects `Fsk_u` or `Fsk_l` depending upon its bit value( either `0` or `1`). The `Logik` block decides which bit of `fsk_data` to be used to set this multiplexer. What I need to do is to implement the counter function for this `Logik` block that increases with every clock cycle and when reached the maximum value will start again with zero.

The architecture of my VHDL code is as follows:

```
signal cnt_s    : std_logic_vector(21 downto 0);
signal temp_s   : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin

process(reset_n_i, clk_128meg_i,cnt_s)

begin

if(reset_n_i='0') then
    cnt_s <= (others=>'0');
elsif (clk_128meg_i'event and clk_128meg_i ='1') then
    if(enable_i='1') then
        cnt_s <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(cnt_s)+1);
```

But, after this I don't have any idea how to proceed. My point is that I need to point the next address of the `fsk_data` register using the `cnt_s` (`cnt_s` acts as a pointer here) in order to select either `fsk_u` or `fsk_l`. I need to know whether my point is right. Help is appreciated in proceeding this code.

Comment: Did you use a DDS compiler for the FSK block? Use a counter or a storage element like BRAM to generate the input bitstream.

Answer (score 2):

If I am not wrong, this is my idea. You want to change your data stream on base of `fsk_data` and use counter for selection purpose. Let say you provide the `fsk_data` to `logik`. Inside your `logik` you have counter that select the pins of `fsk_data` which is 22 bit wide. Use counter of 5 bit & max value equivalent to 21 and `fsk_data(counter_value)` to point `fsk_data` respective bit. Use that value as selection line for mux. Try to run the counter negative edge (not gate with clk) to make it advance for output FF.

Comment: thanks Abdullah. I did the same and got the output as expected.